# error when I setting up REACT environment

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I'm trying to install react native on my Mac through the terminal using "sudo npm install -g expo-cli" but at the end of the installation errors appear.

```
115 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

31 vulnerabilities (19 moderate, 12 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Before trying to install react native I obviously installed nodeJS (16) in its latest version.
Anyone have an idea why the installation doesn't work?

when I do "npm audit fix" this is what it says:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

The first block you're referring to does *not* indicate installation failure. Your packages were installed correctly. The warnings are for nested security vulnerabilities which you can choose to address or ignore, depending on your app.

To prove that it was installed, run `npm list -g` in your terminal and see if `expo-cli` is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the packages installed correctly by creating a new react app using

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

`npm audit fix` is intended to automatically upgrade / fix vulnerabilities in npm packages

Comment: Thx you ! I test with yarn and that work with no errors.

Comment: You can upvote the answer